# how to separate paragraphs in a textfile into multiple textfiles?

Tags: linux

I want to separate this textfile to 3 textfile that each paragraph makes a textfile.(my Os is ubuntu12.04)

Input
 2008  2 2 1120 31.2 L  34.031  48.515 16.7  INS  5 0.3 4.0LINS                1
 GAP=145        0.67       4.1     2.9  6.6  0.2283E-01 -0.1718E+00  0.1289E+02E
 ACTION:UPD 08-12-28 13:25 OP:moh  STATUS:               ID:20080202112031 L   I
 2008-02-02-1120-39S.IN____006                                                 6
 STAT SP IPHASW D HRMM SECON CODA AMPLIT PERI AZIMU VELO AIN AR TRES W  DIS CAZ7
 SNGE BZ EPg      1120 57.69                              91    0.0210  159 318 
 SNGE BZ  AML     1121 24.50      2880.9 0.55                           159 318 
 SHGR BZ EPN5     1121  5.17                              52   -0.0510  215 173 
 GHVR BZ EPn      1121 10.84                              52    0.3610  256  78 
 GHVR BZ ESg      1121 43.50                              91   -0.0210  256  78 
 CHTH BZ EPn      1121 18.26                              52    0.1210  317  48 
 CHTH BZ  AML     1122  8.01       494.0 0.68                           317  48 
 DAMV BZ EPn      1121 23.36                              52   -0.49 9  362  60 
 DAMV BZ  AML     1122  7.03       382.0 0.48                           362  60

2008  211 1403 46.2 L  27.659  55.544 14.1  INS  4 0.1 4.0LINS                1
 GAP=171        0.38       1.7     1.2  3.3 -0.8271E-01 -0.3724E-01  0.4284E+00E
 2008-02-11-1403-37S.INSN__048                                                 6
 ACTION:NEW 08-12-28 13:25 OP:moh  STATUS:               ID:20080211140346 L   I
 STAT SP IPHASW D HRMM SECON CODA AMPLIT PERI AZIMU VELO AIN AR TRES W  DIS CAZ7
 BNDS BZ EPg      14 3 58.14                              90   -0.0710 68.3 115 
 BNDS BN  AML     14 4 26.39      8461.0 0.52                          68.3 115 
 GHIR BZ EPn      14 4 26.40                              52    0.0310  261 286 
 GHIR BN ESg      14 4 59.85                              90   -0.0110  261 286 
 GHIR BN  AML     14 5 25.22      1122.4 0.56                           261 286 
 GHIR BE  AML     14 5 43.83       769.3 0.64                           261 286 
 KRBR BZ EPn      14 4 29.25                              52   -0.1110  284  24 
 KRBR BN ESg      14 5  6.28                              90    0.0010  284  24 
 KRBR BN  AML     14 5 18.89       552.4 0.64                           284  24 
 KRBR BE  AML     14 5 19.22       574.0 0.60                           284  24 
 ZHSF BZ EPn      14 5  3.24                              52    0.25 8  555  66

2008  213 2055 31.5 L  31.713  51.180 14.1  INS  9 0.5 4.2LINS                1
 GAP=127        1.21       4.6     6.5  9.6  0.7570E+01 -0.1161E+02  0.9944E+01E
 ACTION:UPD 08-12-28 13:25 OP:moh  STATUS:               ID:20080213205531 L   I
 2008-02-13-2054-59S.NSN___048                                                 6
 STAT SP IPHASW D HRMM SECON CODA AMPLIT PERI AZIMU VELO AIN AR TRES W  DIS CAZ7
 NASN BZ EPg      2056  3.15                              90   -0.6410  195  51 
 SHGR BZ EPg      2056  8.57                              90   -0.3810  229 282 
 SHGR BN  AML     2056 49.27      2371.2 0.77                           229 282 
 SHGR BE  AML     2056 51.00      2484.4 0.77                           229 282 
 GHVR BZ EPn      2056 18.39                              52    1.0110  307   1 
 GHVR BE  AML     2057 11.42       734.2 0.85                           307   1 
 ASAO BZ EPn      2056 20.35                              52   -0.36 9  332 341 
 ASAO BE ESg      2057  5.23                              90    0.27 9  332 341 
 ASAO BN  AML     2057 15.86       723.3 0.64                           332 341 
 GHIR BZ EPn      2056 31.68                              52    0.48 9  418 155 
 GHIR BN  AML     2057 51.30       259.1 0.79                           418 155 
 DAMV BZ EPn      2056 33.90                              52   -0.27 9  441   9 
 DAMV BN  AML     2057 43.30       237.4 0.65                           441   9 
 THKV BZ EPn      2056 37.71                              52    0.33 8  467 357 
 THKV BE  AML     2057 51.62       205.7 0.72                           467 357 
 ZNJK BZ EPn      2056 53.12                              52   -0.35 7  596 338 
 BNDS BZ EPn      2057  3.72                              52   -0.06 7  680 133

output1.txt
 2008  2 2 1120 31.2 L  34.031  48.515 16.7  INS  5 0.3 4.0LINS                1
 GAP=145        0.67       4.1     2.9  6.6  0.2283E-01 -0.1718E+00  0.1289E+02E
 ACTION:UPD 08-12-28 13:25 OP:moh  STATUS:               ID:20080202112031 L   I
 2008-02-02-1120-39S.IN____006                                                 6
 STAT SP IPHASW D HRMM SECON CODA AMPLIT PERI AZIMU VELO AIN AR TRES W  DIS CAZ7
 SNGE BZ EPg      1120 57.69                              91    0.0210  159 318 
 SNGE BZ  AML     1121 24.50      2880.9 0.55                           159 318 
 SHGR BZ EPN5     1121  5.17                              52   -0.0510  215 173 
 GHVR BZ EPn      1121 10.84                              52    0.3610  256  78 
 GHVR BZ ESg      1121 43.50                              91   -0.0210  256  78 
 CHTH BZ EPn      1121 18.26                              52    0.1210  317  48 
 CHTH BZ  AML     1122  8.01       494.0 0.68                           317  48 
 DAMV BZ EPn      1121 23.36                              52   -0.49 9  362  60 
 DAMV BZ  AML     1122  7.03       382.0 0.48                           362  60

output2.txt
 2008  211 1403 46.2 L  27.659  55.544 14.1  INS  4 0.1 4.0LINS                1
 GAP=171        0.38       1.7     1.2  3.3 -0.8271E-01 -0.3724E-01  0.4284E+00E
 2008-02-11-1403-37S.INSN__048                                                 6
 ACTION:NEW 08-12-28 13:25 OP:moh  STATUS:               ID:20080211140346 L   I
 STAT SP IPHASW D HRMM SECON CODA AMPLIT PERI AZIMU VELO AIN AR TRES W  DIS CAZ7
 BNDS BZ EPg      14 3 58.14                              90   -0.0710 68.3 115 
 BNDS BN  AML     14 4 26.39      8461.0 0.52                          68.3 115 
 GHIR BZ EPn      14 4 26.40                              52    0.0310  261 286 
 GHIR BN ESg      14 4 59.85                              90   -0.0110  261 286 
 GHIR BN  AML     14 5 25.22      1122.4 0.56                           261 286 
 GHIR BE  AML     14 5 43.83       769.3 0.64                           261 286 
 KRBR BZ EPn      14 4 29.25                              52   -0.1110  284  24 
 KRBR BN ESg      14 5  6.28                              90    0.0010  284  24 
 KRBR BN  AML     14 5 18.89       552.4 0.64                           284  24 
 KRBR BE  AML     14 5 19.22       574.0 0.60                           284  24 
 ZHSF BZ EPn      14 5  3.24                              52    0.25 8  555  66

output3.txt
 2008  213 2055 31.5 L  31.713  51.180 14.1  INS  9 0.5 4.2LINS                1
 GAP=127        1.21       4.6     6.5  9.6  0.7570E+01 -0.1161E+02  0.9944E+01E
 ACTION:UPD 08-12-28 13:25 OP:moh  STATUS:               ID:20080213205531 L   I
 2008-02-13-2054-59S.NSN___048                                                 6
 STAT SP IPHASW D HRMM SECON CODA AMPLIT PERI AZIMU VELO AIN AR TRES W  DIS CAZ7
 NASN BZ EPg      2056  3.15                              90   -0.6410  195  51 
 SHGR BZ EPg      2056  8.57                              90   -0.3810  229 282 
 SHGR BN  AML     2056 49.27      2371.2 0.77                           229 282 
 SHGR BE  AML     2056 51.00      2484.4 0.77                           229 282 
 GHVR BZ EPn      2056 18.39                              52    1.0110  307   1 
 GHVR BE  AML     2057 11.42       734.2 0.85                           307   1 
 ASAO BZ EPn      2056 20.35                              52   -0.36 9  332 341 
 ASAO BE ESg      2057  5.23                              90    0.27 9  332 341 
 ASAO BN  AML     2057 15.86       723.3 0.64                           332 341 
 GHIR BZ EPn      2056 31.68                              52    0.48 9  418 155 
 GHIR BN  AML     2057 51.30       259.1 0.79                           418 155 
 DAMV BZ EPn      2056 33.90                              52   -0.27 9  441   9 
 DAMV BN  AML     2057 43.30       237.4 0.65                           441   9 
 THKV BZ EPn      2056 37.71                              52    0.33 8  467 357 
 THKV BE  AML     2057 51.62       205.7 0.72                           467 357 
 ZNJK BZ EPn      2056 53.12                              52   -0.35 7  596 338 
 BNDS BZ EPn      2057  3.72                              52   -0.06 7  680 133

Comment: Either write a tiny program (in C, Python, ....) or learn about `sed` or `ed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you an idea, just one method: iterate your file, row by row.
Save in a buffer all the row while row!="" or row!='\n': in this case, save buffer in a differente file.

```
buffer=""
id=0
cat test | \
while read row; do
  #check row value, save in buffer
  .....
  cat buffer > fileName_${id}.txt
  id=$((id+1))
done
```